# Alt key not working in Emacs SSHing X11

Tags: emacs, ssh, x11

Hello this isn't a coding question but...
I ssh through my mac using X11, and I am using emacs. I am trying to use the "ALT" key for combination but it seems to not be working. I have tried using the "option" key, and "FN + option" both seems to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem before. The hint on http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040425231058862 helps me.

To summarize, you should use xmodmap to remap alt / option in X11.

Put the following in your `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
clear Mod1
keycode 66 = Meta_L
add Mod1 = Meta_L
```

Answer (score 0):

If the emacs instance is somewhere else, which is how I read your question, then it maybe that emacs isn't receiving the correct key when you press alt. 
There are a variety of fixes on http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc20.

However, I'd say that you're probably approaching the problem from the wrong direction. Have you considered running emacs locally, and using TRAMP mode edit the remote files on the local machine?

Comment: Yeah it works when i run emacs locally, but i want to run it through ssh.

Comment: Why would you want to run it over ssh when you could run it locally though?

Comment: For me its simple - native tools - the remote and local OS are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in ~/.emacs

```
(set-keyboard-coding-system nil)
```